Fetch results from sharepoint-list using Frends eiPaaS
Is it possible to connect to Sharepoint and fetch items from a list?
Found in Github a project that lets you download a file but nothing more when it comes to Sharepoint. Should mention that Im running O365-version.

What is an "att list"?

oh, sorry...dont know where they came from... "a list ofcourse", a standard sharepoint-list.

"connect to Sharepoint" using what?

@ScottHunter I assume that is using the iPaaS platform Frends, according to the question's tag frends.

correct, guess I need to be better writing questions...

In my experience, tags are ofter overlooked, so I usually assume they are used only for searching purposes and try to repeat the information they contain in the question's body.

I am not acquainted with Sharepoint, but what you ask seems to be possible according to their documentation: Sharepoint offers a REST API for accessing lists, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest
So, you should be able to integrate with that using RestRequest or HttpRequest tasks.
Note that if you use RestRequest, which requires JSON format, you should include an Accept header with value application/json;odata=verbose according to the Sharepoint documentation I linked above.
I do not have access to a Sharepoint environment to test this out, so any corrections or complements to this answer are very much welcome.

Thanks for the tip, will check it out!
